# How do I create a subdomain with rackspace?

Tags: subdomain, rackspace, rackspace-cloud

I have a site I need to create a subdomain for, managed by rackspace cloud.

The domain is already setup and online. I just need to copy the current www.mysite.com to lab.mysite.com.

How do I go about doing this?

Do I add the subdomain in the cloud sites listing, or under the listing for the domain?

And where do I copy the files to? The current site is at /www.mysite.com/web/content on the ftp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you login to the control panel at Rackspace, you can add subdomains by creating new sites like you would with a regular site. There's more information in the Cloud Sites Knowledge Base: [Creating Sub-domains and/or Domain Aliases](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/content/rackspace-cloud-sites-first-48-3-4-creating-sub-domains-andor-domain-aliases)

Comment: that link is borked. Could this be the correct url? http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/How_do_I_create_a_subdomain%253F

Comment: Yep. Not sure what was up with the link I'd posted.

Comment: Both of those links are completely kaput, try this: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/content/rackspace-cloud-sites-first-48-3-4-creating-sub-domains-andor-domain-aliases

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is much difference between Rackspace Cloud Sites and Rackspace Cloud Servers, and the ways to manage domains/subdomains are also different.

So, if you have a Cloud Sites account, that should be a part of the control panel.

But if you are on a Cloud Server, it's not the same thing :

Login to your NextGen admin panel choose your server, and open the DNS tab.

Here, you can add a record for your domain sub.domain.com to make it match your server's IP.
Then you'll have to tell Apache there's a new domain to deal with (*a virtual host*).

As an example, if you are running an Ubuntu Server, that should work [**something like that**](http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Configure_apache_to_use_virtual_hosts_on_ubuntu_server).

PS: There's also an **[official article](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-create-a-domainsubdomain-that-points-to-a-folder-on-an-existing-website)** in the Rackspace Knowledge Center, but i'm not a fan of the proposed solution.